# Error during the compilation of OpenCV with CUDA and FFMpeg on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I have a requirement to install OpenCV compiled with CUDA and FFMpeg for an optical flow calculation.

I followed [this post](https://www.cerebrumedge.com/single-post/2017/12/26/Compiling-OpenCV-with-CUDA-and-FFMpeg-on-Ubuntu-1604) to install on Ubuntu 18.04, but I am getting the following error shown in the below screenshot when I am trying to execute the following command:

```
  cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
            -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
            -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
            -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
            -D WITH_FFMPEG=1 \
            -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
            -D CUDA_GENERATION=Pascal \
            -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
            -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
            -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
            -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/opt/anaconda/bin/python \
            -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/anaconda/include/python3.5m \
            -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/opt/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5m.so \
            -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5 \
            -D WITH_LAPACK=OFF \
            -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include ..
```

[image]

I have installed the CUDA version 10.0

It would be of a great help, if you can guide me to fix this error or suggest me a different procedure to install OpenCV compiled with CUDA and FFMpeg on Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks!

Comment: looks related to [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6577), the solution seems to be to add another argument to the command line: `-D CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so`

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!

But I got another error in the next process of the compilation during the execution of `make`. I have uploaded the screenshot [Here](https://imgur.com/CBSwsS5).

Answer (score 1):

Just to put the information as an answer

What you describe, seems to be the same issue as in [this one in github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6577) of opencv. In which the CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY is not found. One can set this manually with:

```
-DCUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so
```

or you can also use:

```
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs
```

Which will give a hint of where to look for this library.

For the other problem in your comment, it seems like some python file could not be found. Most probably related to this:

```
        -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/opt/anaconda/bin/python \
        -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/anaconda/include/python3.5m \
        -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/opt/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5m.so \
        -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.5 \
```

You should check if you have those folders/files. If the version is the correct one (3.5) or if it is a newer one (3.6 or 3.7).

Comment: Yes, you were right.  The error was due to improper specification of anaconda and python version. But again during the process of `make` I got another error. I have uploaded the screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/YRGEG7r), can you please help me out?

Comment: @Karthik it looks weird that it says `/usr/localcuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so` in your error and not `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs/libcuda.so` typo copying the path? also, make sure that is the correct path, it could be somewhere else (use `locate libcuda.so` to find where it is)

Comment: Yes there was a typo in the command. But got stuck with another error again the screenshot of the error is uploaded [here](https://imgur.com/vQVriyz). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Karthik you are missing the python-dev package which has that file. I think it is `apt-get install python-dev` but I do not remember now :)